# How to render HTML/Plain Text to the filtering drop-down columns

Tags: filter, calculated-column, cewp

I have a custom list, with some columns. In order to design my list with colors, I used calculated columns with a Content Editor Web Part which contains my script (JavaScript).

I used this script : [Path to SharePoint](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/12/09/color-coding-more-examples/)

It works perfectly, my list have some colors, I just have one issue, the filtering drop-downs columns doesn't render HTML or Plain text but instead my HTML formula as filter:

> DIV style='font-weight:bold etc...

It's not very readable/usefull for the customers/users. I'd like to change that, and display a user-friendly filtering text.

I'm using MOSS (SharePoint 2007), and I don't have access to SharePoint Designer, a solution within a CEWP would be perfect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, where there's text for the date column(let's say you have a date column), and where you can filter the list elements based on the date column, the text for it is showing the actual HTML element?

Comment: When you're looking at your default view, on the column's title, you can click to filter your column right?
If it's a calculated column (which i used to apply color to my list), the filtering drop-downs menu doesn't display plain text nor HTML, but instead my calculated formula :

DIV style='font-weight:bold etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, is since you are already using Javascript, is go into your list view .aspx page, and find the area that defines the view header.  You will find each field containing the text for the column views.  Assign each field a unique ID,

```
<th class="something" id = "column1" ...>
```

Then, in your javascript, add something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementByID("column1").style.color = 'black';
 document.getElementByID("column1").innerHTML = "My new Name";
 ...
</script>
```

On page load, it'll just reset the names back to what you originally want.

Comment: I cannot open my list view .aspx page in SharePoint Designer:

"You do not have permission to do this operation. Ask your web administrator to change your permissions ... "

Comment: Ahh...You know what, I've been working with JS so much lately, that it seems it is always on my mind.  You don't need JS to do this.  Do you have the rights to edit list information?  You can simply go into list options from the website or designer, select the column name you want to modify, and just modify the title to whatever you want.

Comment: @Funnycuni my question to you though, is that after reading the article, is that you have one calc column for te formula, which includes changing the color, and another column with the HTML formula to format it.  It would seem that the format column would have your HTML titel for whatever reason.  Does the user need to see that?  Why not just hide it from their view?

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. It's all the possibilities for filtering that aren't displayed in plain text or HTML. What I colored is my fields in my column, so when I try to filter it, instead of displaying me all my fields in the drop-downs filtering menu, it display me my calculated formula. Here is a screenshot of my problem, maybe it will be more usefull than my words. As you can see, it should display my 3 possibilities (New, In progress, Closed) for filtering in the column "Status".

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/309425Filter.jpg

Comment: Okay, so I think I figured it out.  From what I read from your reference, you have the HTML text in the status column, which holds your options as well.  From what I read, you need to have the one calculated column with the New, In progress, and closed fields, which is your status column.  That column will hold the formula for (like the =CHOOSE(... stuff).  Then, you need ANOTHER column, which will hold the HTML tag, referencing the calculated column.  Right now, it looks like you have the HTML in the Status columns, which is why it shows up when filtering.

Comment: So for example, my column Status is a calculated column, the formula is :
  <DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; color:"&[Color status]&";'"&[Status choice]&"</DIV>

     Color status is my calculated column which will determine my color, Status choice is my choice menu in order to fill the status fields, ans Status is my final column with the colored fields.
   Are you telling me to add an other calculated column?

Comment: What you want, is a column called "Status" like you have, with JUST the text options, it is not a calculated column, it only displays the status in text.  The next column you want is a color column, with a formula like =CHOOSE(FIND("e",[Status],1),,"black",,,,"limegreen",,,"gold","red",,,,,"darkorange").  So now you have two columns.  Finally, you want a third column with ="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; color:"&Color&";'>"&[Status]&"</DIV>" Only.  This should then work

Comment: This is exactly what I have...

Comment: You said though your status column is a calculated column with <DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; color:"&[Color status]&";'"&[Status choice]&"</DIV>.  If you are filtering on status, that is all that will come up.

Comment: I use a script in a CEWP in order to render the formula in HTML within the SharePoint list.
I want to display in my list the calculated column with the formula "<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; color:"&Color&";'>"&[Status]&"</DIV>"  so that the CEWP will render the fields with colors.
It works, except for the filtering menu.
If I only display the "Status" column, it's just my choice menu whithout colors.
Am I wrong? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, I had an important task with work to address, and I left this question hanging :(  In the meantime, I tried to replicate what the site had instructed.  I went through everything except getting the script (don't want to add internet scripts to my work), and you have everything correct.  You're getting those filter options because that is what is actually in the field, the script just turns it into an HTML element, but doesn't change what'S actually written into the field.

Comment: If you want it to be different, you either have to modify the script itself to write the HTML elements into the filter list, or write your own script to do it.  The other option, is to just not let the user use this option to filter the list.

Comment: Ok thank you Brandon, I will try to modify the script to finally display the HTML elements into the filter list.
I don't know how long this will take, but I will give it a try :)

Comment: I don't understand why my calculated formula is encoded in the code view (ctrl U) of my list.
I took a look at the SPEncode.HtmlDecode Method in order to decode that, but I don't know how to use it.